# How to check tax rules in the invoice page of Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to check tax rules of each product in invoice page.

Is there any variable that stores tax rules such as 8% or 18% ?

It would be something like this

```
{if $order_invoice->tax_rule == "18%"}
    ...
{/if}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Check the right variable

You won't find this data in `$order_invoice`. If you want to get tax rules for each product, you'll need to check the `$order_detail` var. Extract from [**`invoice.tpl`**](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6/pdf/invoice.tpl#L129) :

```
<!-- PRODUCTS -->
{foreach $order_details as $order_detail}
{cycle values='#FFF,#DDD' assign=bgcolor}
<tr style="line-height:6px;background-color:{$bgcolor};">
    <!-- Here we've got one line, for one product -->
    <!-- This product's datas are stored in $order_detail -->
</tr>
```

You can find the tax rate in `$order_detail.tax_rate`. Unfortunately, it always return `0.000`.

**Yes... This data is not filled... sad day...**

---

### Create an `OrderDetail` override

Create the `OrderDetail.php` file in the [**`override/classes/order/`**](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.6/override/classes/order) folder, containing this code :

```
class OrderDetail extends OrderDetailCore
{

    /**
     * Get order products
     *
     * @return array Products with price, quantity (with taxe and without)
     */
    public function getProducts($products = false, $selectedProducts = false, $selectedQty = false)
    {
        if (!$products)
            $products = $this->getProductsDetail();

        $order = new Order($this->id_order);
        $customized_datas = Product::getAllCustomizedDatas($order->id_cart);

        $resultArray = array();
        foreach ($products as $row)
        {
            // Retrieve tax rate
            $product = new Product($row['product_id']);
            $row['tax_rate'] = $product->getTaxesRate();

            // Change qty if selected
            if ($selectedQty)
            {
                $row['product_quantity'] = 0;
                foreach ($selectedProducts as $key => $id_product)
                    if ($row['id_order_detail'] == $id_product)
                        $row['product_quantity'] = (int)($selectedQty[$key]);
                if (!$row['product_quantity'])
                    continue;
            }

            $this->setProductImageInformations($row);
            $this->setProductCurrentStock($row);
            $this->setProductCustomizedDatas($row, $customized_datas);

            // Add information for virtual product
            if ($row['download_hash'] && !empty($row['download_hash']))
            {
                $row['filename'] = ProductDownload::getFilenameFromIdProduct((int)$row['product_id']);
                // Get the display filename
                $row['display_filename'] = ProductDownload::getFilenameFromFilename($row['filename']);
            }

            $row['id_address_delivery'] = $order->id_address_delivery;

            /* Stock product */
            $resultArray[(int)$row['id_order_detail']] = $row;
        }

        if ($customized_datas)
            Product::addCustomizationPrice($resultArray, $customized_datas);

        return $resultArray;
    }

}
```

This override allows us to edit the `tax_rate` value.
I simply added these two lines in the `getProducts()` function :

```
foreach ($products as $row)
{
    // Retrieve tax rate
    $product = new Product($row['product_id']);
    $row['tax_rate'] = $product->getTaxesRate();

    // ...
}
```

### Create an `OrderInvoice` override

Create the `OrderInvoice.php` file in the [**`override/classes/order/`**](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.6/override/classes/order) folder.
This class will contain **the same code** as our previous override. Just change the first lines :

```
<?php

class OrderInvoice extends OrderInvoiceCore
{
    // Copy/Paste the same code
}
```

And now, you can display the tax rate for each product, using `{$order_detail.tax_rate}` !!

### (Bonus) Edit your template

Let's change this template (here : [**`pdf/invoice.tpl`**](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6/pdf/invoice.tpl#L104)) to add a "Tax rule" column :

```
<tr style="line-height:4px;">
    <!-- Remove 10% from the first column header width -->
    <td style="text-align: left; background-color: #4D4D4D; color: #FFF; padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold; width: {if !$tax_excluded_display}25%{else}35%{/if}">{l s='Product / Reference' pdf='true'}</td>
    ...
    <!-- Add our new column header, 10% width -->
    <td style="background-color: #4D4D4D; color: #FFF; text-align: right; font-weight: bold; width: 10%; white-space: nowrap;">{l s='Tax rate' pdf='true'}</td>
    ...
</tr>
<!-- PRODUCTS -->
{foreach $order_details as $order_detail}
{cycle values='#FFF,#DDD' assign=bgcolor}
<tr style="line-height:6px;background-color:{$bgcolor};">
    <!-- Remove 10% from the first column width -->
    <td style="text-align: left; width: {if !$tax_excluded_display}25%{else}35%{/if}">{$order_detail.product_name}{if isset($order_detail.product_reference) && !empty($order_detail.product_reference)} ({l s='Reference:' pdf='true'} {$order_detail.product_reference}){/if}</td>
    ...
    <!-- Add our new column, 10% width -->
    <td style="text-align: right; width: 10%; white-space: nowrap;">
        {$order_detail.tax_rate}
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried it on a new Prestashop 1.6 to check and it worked. Have you got anything which can interfer ?

Comment: Nope. I created OrderDetail.php in that override folder. And tried to get data from $order_detail.tax_rate in invoice.tpl and it gives 0.000

Comment: Do you use `/override/class/order` folder ? Have you cleared you Prestashop cache ?

Comment: Yes exactly this folder and i cleared cache, still gettig 0.000

Comment: First, I would delete the `cache/class_index.php` file, and check if my override is called (using any debug tool).

Comment: i don't know how to check if it is called or not ?

Comment: Add `echo "Called."; die;` in your override's `getProducts()` function. If you see the message, it's called. Otherwise, it's not.

Comment: I added it and opened an invoice, still seeing invoice as normal ?? so it seems your override is not called, how can i make it called ?

Comment: **1.** Be sure the file is in `override/class/order/`. **2.** Delete `cache/class_index.php`. There's nothing more to do.

Comment: should i add your code to original OrderDetail.php file ? I tried it without any luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56774/discussion-between-zessx-and-rule101).

Answer (score 0):

I think correct way is to override getPriducts() function in OrderInvoice.php

```
foreach ($products as $row)
{
...
$sql = "SELECT tax.rate FROM ps_tax as tax join `ps_order_detail_tax` on ps_order_detail_tax.id_tax = tax.id_tax WHERE ps_order_detail_tax.id_order_detail = " .(int)$row['id_order_detail'] ;
$result = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
$tmp = $result[0];
if (isset($tmp['rate'])){
            $row['tax_rate_product'] = $tmp['rate'];
}
else { //No Tax
$row['tax_rate_product'] = "0.000";
}
...
}
```

and use rate value in .tpl

```
...
<td style="text-alig: right; width: 15%">{$order_detail.tax_rate_product}</td>
...
```

remember to delete cache/class_index.php

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have a product tax rule depending on shipment address. Try

```
foreach ($products as $row)
```

{

```
...

// Retrieve tax rate

$product = new Product($row['product_id']);
$row['tax_rate'] = $product->getTaxesRate(new Address((int)$order->id_address_delivery))
 ...
```